# How to align Conky text to centre of desktop?

Tags: themes, conky

I am working on creating an entire Theme based off of Coldplay's Mylo Xyloto album. This is my first time working with Conky and theme creation. I started off by creating the Conky setup:

[image]

I would like to how to centre the text in Conky. First to have it placed in the centre of my desktop, and second to have the text centre (think the Centre align button in word). It is supposed to be aligned like the album art:

[image]

Conky Script

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1230966/

---

End Result using Answer bellow: [image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can i get your conky script?

Comment: I will add it to the post.

Comment: paste it on paste.ubuntu.com and give me the link

Comment: Wow that's a cool site: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1230966/

Comment: Nice! If you have a question about conky, just ping my nick at chat room. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put your conky on top center, find **alignment tl** line 37 in you conky script and put this

```
alignment top_middle 

gap_x 0
gap_y 0
```

**Allignment code**

```
top_left

top_middle

top_right
```

To center your text put

${alignc} on :

```
${alignc}${font ETIAW v3:size=75}${time %A}${font}
${alignc}${font ETIAW v3:size=75}${time %B} ${time %e}${font}
${alignc}${font ETIAW v3:size=75}${time %I:%M %p}${font}
```

[**Conky script basic**](http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html)

My output as im not using your font :

[image]

Comment: Beautifu :) Where does the Allignment code go? top_left

top_middle

top_right

Comment: top_middle if you want it to be center of your desktop :)

Comment: Ah I see :) It is in the middle now, but it is all the way at the top. I would want it right in the centre of the desktop. Any suggestions?

Comment: use middle_middle ;)

Comment: I seemed to heave figured it out :D I tweaked the gap_y to 250, it is not exactly where I needed it to be. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem man! Enjoy Ubuntu!